# Minify RequireJS modules that were loaded afterwards

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I'm building up a medium sized Single Page WebApp on the basis of RequireJS and a .NET Backend, which handles the Ajax "page changes" for me.
Each time a page is loaded for the first time, a module controller (JS) loads the corresponding JS-Module.

I'm working in SublimeText 2 and have built up a configuration that compiles and minifies my JS on save into one single file. The configuration is saved in a require.config call.

This works fine for all the dependencies that are trackable by RequireJS. However I'd like to improve the build process to also minify modules (best would be folders) that are not directly required and be saved separately in another folder.

Here is my RequireJS Config:

```
require.config({
    appDir: ''
,   paths: {
        'jquery': [
            '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min'
        ,   'lib/jquery'
        ]
    ,   'underscore': [
            '//raw.github.com/documentcloud/underscore/master/underscore-min'
        ,   'lib/underscore'
        ]
    ,   'modernizr': 'lib/modernizr'
    ,   'jquery-ui': 'lib/jquery-ui'
    }
,   shim: {
        'jquery-ui': { deps: ['jquery'] }
    ,   'lib/jquery-tablesorter': { deps: ['jquery'], exports: 'jQuery.fn.tablesorter' }
    ,   'underscore': { exports: '_' }
    }
,   exclude: ['jquery', 'jquery-ui', 'underscore']
,   name: 'main'
,   out: '../min/main.js'
,   optimize: 'none'
});

require(['jquery', 'modules/ModuleController', 'jquery-ui', 'util/Log'], 
    function($, Controller) {
        // jQuery was extended by jqueryUI
        // window.log is now accessible

        $(function(){
            Controller.setup({
                objGlobal: window.RecruitingApp
            });
        })
});
```

My folder structure looks like this:

```
/AppRoot
    /dev
        /lib
        /modules
        /util
        build.js
        main.js
    /min
        /lib
        /* here i'd like to have a generated modules folder with the minified modules */
        main.js
```

The Module Loader looks like this:

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore'], function($, _) {
    var i = {
    };

    var o = {
        objGlobal: null
    };

    var objModules = {};

    var setup = function(options) {
        o = $.extend(o, options);

        o.objGlobal.moduleListener = function(module) {
            require(['modules/'+module+''], function(Module){
                if(objModules.module && _.isFunction(objModules.module.destroy)) {
                    objModules.module.destroy();
                }

                o.objGlobal.currentModule = module;
                objModules.module = Module;
                Module.setup();
            });
        };

        o.objGlobal.moduleListener(o.objGlobal.currentModule);
    }

    // method interface
    i.setup = setup;

    return i;
});
```

Is it possible to change the RequireJS Config File to automatically minify every file in a folder and save them in a corresponding folder?

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, you are already using require.js optimization tool "r.js".

r.js has two ways of optimizing your code, first way is when you want to optimize single module and it's dependencies into single js file, and second approach is to optimize whole project/multiple modules.

You can achieve that by using "modules" option in you r.js build config. [Take a look here.](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html#wholeproject)